# Mapshaper -proj resulting shapes in wrong Hemisphere

Tags: wgs84, proj, utm, mapshaper, prj

I have shapefiles that I am projecting in Mapshaper, however when I use `-proj WGS84` the end-result (topoJSON) has the shapes in the Northern Hemisphere, rather than the Southern Hemisphere.

On inspecting the shapefiles using `info` it shows `'CRS: +proj=utm +zone=55 +datum=WGS84` which to me indicates the default is UTM55N, not 55S as I want it to be.

When I explicitly specify UTM55S using `-proj from=EPSG:32755 crs=EPSG:4326` I get the correct end-result with the shapes in the Southern hemisphere.

The prj file contained within the shapefiles zip appears to specify 55**S**:

`PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_55S",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",147.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Why can't I use `-proj WGS84`? Do I need to change the prj file or is the only solution to keep explicitly referring to the EPSG number for **S** (because perhaps it defaults to **N**?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting the answer to my own question as Matt Bloch fixed the bug - github response here: https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/issues/474

(The bug caused some prj files for UTM zones in the southern hemisphere to be parsed incorrectly)

Answer (score 0):

Mapshaper is probably using a bit older version of the Proj library. GDAL version 3.3.0dev does find the info about south. The only place in the .prj file where the "zone 55S" appears is the name of the CRS system and older Proj probably does not interpret it. Name is generally not supposed to be meaningful. In the OGC WKT2:2018 variant the hemisphere appears in the conversion method `CONVERSION["UTM zone 55S",`.

```
gdalsrsinfo south.prj

PROJ.4 : +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 55S",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 55S",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",147,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]],
        ID["EPSG",17055]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```